# postgresql consulta between

Tags: postgresql

A tabela X tem a seguinte informação:

```
(id serial unique, vlinicial numeric(10,2), vlfinal numeri(10,2))

ID VLINICIAL VLFINAL
--------------------
1   0.01     10000.00
2   10000.01 20000.00
3   20000.01 30000.00
4   30000.01 40000.00
5   40000.01 999999.00
```

A minha consulta para verificar qual o ID escolher:

```
select * from x where 17000.00 between vlinicial and vlfinal
```

O resultado deveria ser o ID 2 mas acontece que dá 0 linhas...

Se colocar uma valor abaixo de 10000.00 já aparece o ID 1:

```
select * from x where 7000.00 between vlinicial and vlfinal
```

Testei desta forma e resultou, mas não consulta acima não.

```
select id 
from
(select 1 as id, 0.01::numeric as vli, 10000.00::numeric as vlf
union all
select 2 as id, 10000.01::numeric as vli, 20000.00::numeric as vlf
union all
select 3 as id, 20000.01::numeric as vli, 30000.00::numeric as vlf
union all
select 4 as id, 30000.01::numeric as vli, 40000.00::numeric as vlf) as t1   
where 15000.00::numeric between t1.vli and t1.vlf
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual versao do PostGreSQL você etsa usando? Testei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22330/2) e funciona

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade, 9.6

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade olha aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/04e99/5, está funcionando

Comment: @Groot Funciona no 9.6 também: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/22330/1). Tem certeza que a tabela X foi preenchida?

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade, sim, tabela preenchida com toda a informação, e já parti a cabeça com isto que é muito estranho... vou analisar detalhadamente a ver o que está errado. obrigado.

Comment: @Groot  Há a chande de estar com a inserção dos dados não comitada?   Dependendo da configuração do software cliente, por exemplo pgadmin, é possível deixar o autocommit desabilitado